# Is it possible to mount a partition only for some users?

Tags: filesystems, mount

This thread comes from [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/123615/external-ext4-card-mounted-only-for-root-on-android-5-1-64-bits). Even when it is an Android question,
I think the theoretical command line part should better be asked here.

In short: I have achieved to mount a Ext4 file system, but this mount only **exists for root** user.

**Details**:

```
root@unknown:/ # mount | grep "sdcard" -i
/dev/block/mmcblk1p1 /storage/sdcard1 ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
root@unknown:/ # exit
u0_a98@unknown:/ $ mount | grep "sdcard"
u0_a98@unknown:/ $ mount | grep "mmcblk"
```

As can be seen, the **normal user can not see** the device as mounted. This is, obviously, very different from having *no permissions* to access it.
This could be some sort of bug, by the way.

Or **is it possible** to do this on Linux?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, but this might help: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt

Comment: interesting info. Maybe we have here some of those "private mount" cases.

Comment: Check "Mount namespaces (CLONE_NEWNS)" in http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html
Although I don't know if there's proper support for this in major distro.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in Linux if the kernel / OS has support for Linux Containers (LXC).  (And I think this is what Android is using ...)

For example, you create a new shell with its own mount namespace like this:

```
  $ lxc-unshare -s MOUNT /bin/bash
```

References:

- The "lxc-unshare" manual entry: https://linuxcontainers.org/it/lxc/manpages/man1/lxc-unshare.1.html
- RedHat's ["Introduction to Linux Containers](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1353593)"

---

> This could be some sort of bug, by the way.

No.  It is not a bug.